# How to stream music from a Mac to an iOS device?

Tags: ios, mac, audio, streaming

I have an MP3 file that I'd like to stream from my Mac to an iOS. I think VLC can be used to achieve this, but I couldn't find the right settings on the VLC app and in iOS.

If I pick RTP multicast, for instance, how can I listen to this stream in iOS?

Eventually, I'd like to be able to do this from a live audio from the microphone, but I think the MP3 stage should come first.

Any thoughts?

Comment: if you want this to be from a microphone eventually, can you just skip ahead to this?
skype can certainly stream audo from a mac to a phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Airfoil from [Rogue Amoeba](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) can stream audio from the Mac to many other devices, including iOS. It will capture any audio running on your system, either from a specific input (e.g. Mic), application, or the entire system audio.

[image: "Select a source" menu from Airfoil]

> **Airfoil Speakers Touch**
>
> Airfoil Speakers Touch runs on iPhones, iPods
>   Touch, and iPads running iOS 4.0 or higher. Use it to send audio to
>   your iOS device when connected to your local network! Airfoil Speakers
>   Touch works exclusively with Airfoil for Mac and Airfoil for Windows.